# Default Billing and Shipping address

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, address

I would like to check when a customer click on **“Place Order”**, if he has a default billing and shipping address.

If no, I would like to put the addresses of the order by default for this customer.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I just give you a suggestion. We should take a look at: `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement::_prepareCustomerQuote()`. We will see how Magento will set the default billing and shipping address for customer when placing order.

**[Note]** I have checked the default Magento, if a new customer has no default shipping address. It will set the order shipping address as default shipping. My Magento version is 2.2.2.